# What does the ngModel directive documentation mean exactly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm beginner to AngularJs but now I have used and understand how AngularJs works quite a bit.
The thing which I want to ask about is the few lines in the `ngModel` directive documentation.

These lines are:

> Note: ngModel will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the
>   expression on the current scope. If the property doesn't already exist
>   on this scope, it will be created implicitly and added to the scope.

I don't understand what they are trying to say. I do know that the `ngModel` directive binds a property to the `input`, `select` and `textarea` controls. Just like a very simple code below:

```
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="myName">
{{myName}}
```

So, can anybody come up with any other precise example which helps me to understand those lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngModel` is a standard way that Angular binds a scope property (usually declared in a controller) to the UI.

So, typically, a controller is created with the property declared inside:

```
angular.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.myProperty = '';

});
```

And you would bind it to the UI like this:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myProperty"/>
</div>
```

In this example `$scope` is scoped in the UI on the `div` element because the `ng-controller` attribute binds the `Ctrl` to that element.

However, Angular allows you to be a bit *lazy* as well and not bother defining the `myProperty` in the controller:

```
angular.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

});
```

And still using it in the UI:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myProperty"/>
</div>
```

In this case Angular will implicitly (dynamically) create a `myProperty` on `$scope`.  That can be used in the UI inside the `ng-controller`'s scope.

This can be used for *UI only* properties that you don't want to bother the controller about.  An example would be when you want to hide/show something based on a user's interaction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your such precise and explanatory answer. Ok. what will happen if I use only {{myName}} which is actually observing directive in DOM and dont use at all the ng-model directive. Will it also do the same?

Comment: No, it is the binding to the `input` directive that causes the property to be created. As far as I can see...http://plnkr.co/edit/FN9AeEuiimbtHr3iTO7R?p=preview

Comment: However, other Angular directives act like this as well.  So, it is not only a feature we see with `input`.

Comment: @Rohaan: `{{...}}` are expressions in AngularJs to help you write to the DOM. They are not binding instructions and as such they are not creating the property if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have a controller with a `$scope`.
You can init your $scope with values(e.g.):

```
$scope.myName= 'test';
```

And then you input will have a default value of `test`.

```
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="myName">
{{myName}}
```

You can choose not to init your scope with the value, and then `$scope.myName` will be created behind the scenes and bound with no default value.

Comment: thanks for your quick and precise response. Can you please tell me if i use {{myName}} which is observing directive then in that case it will do the same. I mean it will dynamically create the property for scope?

Comment: Yes. When your controller kicks in, you have a place where you can init stuff. Your scope by default has nothing on it. If you want add a model to your scope that's your place. If you don't add properties to your model they will be added automatically by the ng-model directive.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down:

```
Note: ngModel will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the expression
on the current scope. If the property doesn't already exist on this scope, it
will be created implicitly and added to the scope.
```

1) ngModel will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the expression on the current scope.

So if you have the element:

```
<input ng-model="theProperty">
```

This element will have a scope:

```
var theScope = element.scope()
```

Most of the times this scope is accessed in a controller constructor... now, let's go back to the statement:

```
 will try to bind to the property given... on the current scope.
```

Note that it says "*try*" because it is possible that the current scope contains the property or not. Because angular will do something like this:

```
 theScope['theProperty'] = the_inputs_value;
```

When the property did not exist, the property gets created. So this explains the next statement.

```
 If the property doesn't already exist on this scope, 
 it will be created implicitly and added to the scope.
```

Comment: nice break down :) It also really helped me

Comment: also, this site has lots of examples... might be helpful for beginners... ngtutorial.com/guide